# How do you make an enum decodable by its case name and not its raw value?

Tags: swift, enums, decodable

If I have an enum like this:

```swift
enum SomeEnum: String {
  case case1 = "raw value 1"
  case case2 = "raw value 2"
}
```

How would I make it conform to `Decodable` by using the case name (`case1` and `case2`) instead of the raw values? For example, I would be able to use it like this:

```swift
let data = Data("\"case1\"".utf8)
let decodedEnum = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SomeEnum.self, from: data) // SomeEnum.case1
```

---

#### Edit

I added this to `SomeEnum` like what @Alexander said:

```swift
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case case1, case2
}
```

but I still got the error

> The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.

---

#### Edit 2

I tried explicitly defining the raw values in the `CodingKeys` like what @Lutz said, but I got the same error. Just in case `JSONDecoder` didn't allow fragmented JSON, I tried using an array of `SomeEnum`s (`#"["case1", "case2"]"#`, which also didn't work.

Comment: define a `CodingKeys` enum for this enum.

Comment: @Alexander I tried that but it still didn't work.

Comment: `"\"case1\""` is not a valid JSON. That's what the issue says.

Comment: It's valid according to some specs, but with JSONSerialization, you need to allow fragment. Show the final usecase. Is it a key or a value?

Comment: @PGDev Funnily enough, using `"\"raw value 1\""` (without the coding keys) works. I still tried using an array of `SomeEnum`s but I still got the same error.

Comment: @Larme The enum will be a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into it and the problem here is that what you see in the JSON result is an encoded *value*, not a *key*. Consequently, adding `CodingKeys` won't help.

A slightly complicated solution uses a custom protocol and a corresponding extension to achieve the goal.

With that, you can declare:

```swift
    enum Test: String, CaseNameCodable {
        case one = "Number One"
        case two = "Number Two"
    }
```

and it would do what you need.

A complete working example is sketched below (works for me in a Playground in Xcode 11.2):

```swift
    import Foundation

    // A custom error type for decoding...
    struct CaseNameCodableError: Error {
        private let caseName: String

        init(_ value: String) {
            caseName = value
        }

        var localizedDescription: String {
            #"Unable to create an enum case named "\#(caseName)""#
        }
    }

    //
    // This is the interesting part:
    //

    protocol CaseNameCodable: Codable,  RawRepresentable ,  CaseIterable {}

    extension CaseNameCodable {

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let value = try container.decode(String.self)
            guard let raw = Self.allCases.first(where: { $0.caseName == value })?.rawValue else { throw CaseNameCodableError(value) }
            self.init(rawValue: raw)!
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(caseName)
        }

        private var caseName: String {
            return "\(self)"
        }
    }

    //
    // Now you can use the protocol CaseNameCodable just like you
    // would use Codable (on RawRepresentable enums only)
    //

    enum Test: String, CaseNameCodable {
        case one = "Number One"
        case two = "Number Two"
    }

    // EXAMPLE:

    // Create a test value
    let testValue = Test.one

    // encode it and convert it to a String
    let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(testValue)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!

    print (jsonString) // prints: "one"

    // decode the same data to produce a decoded enum instance
    let decodedTestValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: jsonData)

    print(decodedTestValue.rawValue) // prints: Number One
```

Comment: nice one! I'd go for getting a case itself in a guard, and just do `self = raw` instead of force unwrapping. also there is `DecodingError` which provides debug description formatting for free, so you don't have to define a custom one.